# php cant parse a c\ properties.settings file because of one of the fields names?

Tags: c#, php, xml

I have a simple c# application, which pulls key information from its internally generated Properties.Settings file. In essence this is a timing system to trigger events. I am now writing a web GUI to allow users to modify the settings as this service (the c# one) is running on a server.

The problem is this. While parsing the xml file within PHP, I can not parse past the following line:

```
 <userSettings>
    <TimingSystem.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="Time1" serializeAs="String">
            <value>14:08</value>
        </setting>
```

TimingSystem.Properties.Settings is throwing an error in the code because PHP doesnt like the tag here is the code:

```
    $mycode = simplexml_load_file('TimingSystem.exe.config');
    $Time1 = $mycode->configuration->userSettings->TimingSystem.Properties.Settings->setting['Time1']->value;
```

its returning the error:

Trying to get property of non-object

and

syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

How can I resolve this so it can parse the settings file. I am not keen on re-writing my program to use a regular xml file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try wrapping the '.' separated tree name in `{'xxx'}` like:

```
$mycode = simplexml_load_file('TimingSystem.exe.config');
$Time1 = $mycode->configuration->userSettings->{'TimingSystem.Properties.Settings'}->setting['Time1']->value;
```

not 100% sure it will work, but worth a go.  let me know what happens.

alternatively, make it a variable.

```
$treeName = 'TimingSystem.Properties.Settings';
$Time1 = $mycode->configuration->userSettings->$treeName->setting['Time1']->value;
```

Comment: its not pulling an error but now I simply cant seem to get any values back. Am I asking to parse incorrectly?

Comment: so a `var_dump` on the parsed object.. i.e. `var_dump($mycode);` to see what the parser is bringing back..

Comment: Looks like I get the entire XML back. I think I just need to go and figure out the tree values I need to input!

Comment: make sure the returned value is an object, and not an array, as this will cause the error you are seeing.. it may be you have to use array access, like `$mycode['configuration']['userSettings']....`

Comment: possibly `setting['Time1']` is incorrect, so try look at `var_dump($mycode->configuration->userSettings->{'TimingSystem.Properties.Settings'}->setting);`

Comment: DONE! 
    $Time1 = $mycode->userSettings->$treename->setting[0]->value;

Thank you for all your help. really appreciated :)